# Extracting & manipulating an object from a jQuery collection

Tags: jquery, object, collections, reference

I'm using jQuery to create a typical collection of list items like so:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="slides">
  <li>Slide 1</li>
  <li>Slide 2</li>
  <li>Slide 3</li>
  <li>Slide 4</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $slides = $('#slides li');
```

What I'd like to do is then identify e.g. the currently-visible slide within the collection, then transition from that slide into the next.

I thought the following would *Just Work™* but instead of an object reference, the `$current` variable holds a string literal of the target slide's markup:

**jQuery**

```
var $current = $slides[0];
    console.log($current); // returns "<li>Slide 1</li>" and not [object]
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I expected the above to give me a unique reference to the object I selected in the collection, but I don't understand why jQuery isn't working like that here and decides to give me a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function()
{
    var $slides = $('#slides li');
    var $current = $($slides[0]);
    console.log($current); 
});
```

Difference between `$('#slides li')` and `$('#slides')` is first select the all the `li` `object` while second one just select entire `ul#slides` as `object` so you can not access first `li` as `$slides[0]` because it will always return `ul object`.

Comment: Thanks, Dipesh. I did mean $('#slides li') but made a mistake whilst trying to make the code succinct here.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* a reference to the element. However, what you're seeing in the console is a browser-dependent string representation of that element - in this case its `outerHTML`.

Take a look at the console output of [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gxTcU/1/).

Comment: I made a mistake in trying to extract the specific problem from my existing code, in that the selector should indeed have been $('#slides li'). I've updated the OP now.

Comment: @markedup That doesn't really change much, though; what you're seeing in the console is still the browser's representation of the element - your variable **does** reference the element directly, it's not a string.

Comment: But if I try to do something like $current.fadeOut() I get an 'unsupported method' error. Dipesh's approach works as I expected.

Comment: @markedup Because `.fadeOut()` is a jQuery method (called on a jQuery object), and doing `$slides[0]` returns the actual DOM element, not a jQuery object. If you want that particular `<li>` element wrapped in a jQuery object, use `.eq()`. Dipesh's answer works because he's re-wrapping it as a jQuery object, but that's unnecessary if you use the correct jQuery functions to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Haven't used `.eq()` before, but I can see how that works now as well. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
 var $slides = $('#slides li');
 var $current = $slides[0];
```

you can than manipulate the current slide like this for example:

```
 $($current).fadeOut();
```

edit: just saw Dipesh Parmar answer, you can do that aswell ;)

just dont forget that what you where working with was string's, if you need jquery to use that string as it was an object put it inside $()

Comment: It's ***not*** a string, though, it's an element.